# Does the Asus P8P67 Pro have a scheduled boot option?

Tags: windows-7, boot, motherboard, bios

I have a custom built computer with an Asus P8P67 Pro motherboard and an i5 2500K CPU, running Windows 7 64 bit. Is it possible to setup this motherboard (if needed using the BIOS) to boot at 17h15 mon through thu and 16h15 on Friday if the computer is not in sleep, hibernate, standby or anything else of that sort (just turned off, but with the power plug connected and the IO switch in the I position)? And if so, where can I set this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my Bios and it does indeed have an option for a scheduled boot. It is a global scheduled boot, though: You cannot set different boot times for different days. you set one hour and it boots at that hour every day.